# Excel VBA - SaveAs Template on Sharepoint does not create new document

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have code that opens a template, populates the template and saves the template with a new name.

This works perfectly fine on my local drive.

However, I now need it to work on sharepoint and for some reason I cannot fathom, it opens the template, populates the template, then saves the template with the same name and does not create a new spreadsheet.

```
Dim saveName as String
Dim fileName as String
Dim sjk as Workbook
fileName = Thisworkbook.Path & Application.PathSeperator & "Template.xlsx"
Set sjk = Workbooks.Open(filename)

saveName = PPD.Range("C100")

sjk.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & saveName & ".xlsx"
sjk.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

I have debug.print the saveName and ThisWorkbook.Path and everything appears fine, the output that should be "saved as" is exactly how it should be....

But I don't get a new spreadsheet.

This isn't a permissions thing, I can run a simpler macro in a different spreadsheet and create a saved excel here called "test.xlsx" but I cannot seem to get this code to work.

If there are any errors of syntax above please ignore, the syntax is right in the code, but I have it on a different machine and typed it by hand here....it works on the local drive syntax errors of a missed capital will not be the issue.

Any help gratefully received as I have been banging my head against the wall for hours, trying different variations of getting the saveName output to change....but all to no avail.

For the ThisWorkBook.Path - it finds the template...so it has the right path and it saves the template....it just doesn't create a new version with a new name...which is freaking me out....

Comment: PPD isn't the problem, it is the name of a Sheet it is the code name.  As I say, it works fine on my local drive and also when I look at saveName it takes the information from PPD and puts it there exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a lot more testing, I have come to realise....there is nothing wrong with my code.

The issue is in the name that is being used to save the document.  To many spaces, too many letters...who knows, you can have that document with that name on sharepoint, but what you can't do is macro save that document with that name to sharepoint.

If I ever find a workaround I will post it for anyone facing similar problems.